# Can't establish AP with hostapd on RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, access-point

I'm running raspian and am attempting to use my Raspberry Pi to establish an AP using `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`. So far, I can't get `hostapd` to work. The relevant `lsusb` is

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

I've also tried using another adapter, with the RT5372 chipset, and same error.

My hostapd.conf file in /etc/hostapd/ is

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=MyPiAP
hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
#ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
#ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=MyWifiPassword
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

When I run sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf, I get

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

Any ideas about what could be causing this? Are these chipsets that can't host APs?